# Android FaceDetection and frame data pairing

Tags: android, android-camera, face-detection

Currently I am creating an android app that wants to pick out faces from a camera feed, in which I can do more analyzing later.

At the moment, I have instantiated a camera object, on which I have called .setPreviewCallback() and .setFaceDetectionListener(), and have overridden the corresponding methods accordingly.

What I am wondering is when onFaceDetection() is called, I want to get the frame data that it detected the face on. At the moment my work around is to pair it with onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera), in which I set some boolean in onFaceDetection() that causes the byte[] data from onPreviewFrame to be saved. However, I am unsure of whether onPreviewFrame() or onFaceDetection() is called first.

So I guess in essence, my question is:
1. What is called first... onPreviewFrame() or onFaceDetection()?
OR
2. How would I go about getting the frame data that onFaceDetection() corresponds to?